# DTS: Overwriting pin configuration

Tags: linux, hardware, device-tree

I'm setting up a custom device and I need to disable some pins in the dts. Can I just overwrite the pins in the dts file or do I need to change them in the dtsi file. Note that I do want to keep the other pin assignments.

The dtsi file contains the following.

```
&iomuxc {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_hog>;

    imx6qdl-var-som-mx6 {

        pinctrl_hog: hoggrp {
            fsl,pins = <
                /* CTW6120 IRQ */
                MX6QDL_PAD_EIM_DA7__GPIO3_IO07      0x80000000
                /* for Bluetooth/wifi enable */
                MX6QDL_PAD_SD3_DAT6__GPIO6_IO18     0x1b0b1
                /* SDMMC2 CD/WP */
                MX6QDL_PAD_KEY_COL4__GPIO4_IO14     0x80000000
                MX6QDL_PAD_KEY_ROW4__GPIO4_IO15     0x80000000
                /* USBOTG ID pin */
                /*MX6QDL_PAD_GPIO_4__GPIO1_IO04     0x80000000*/
                /* PMIC INT */
                MX6QDL_PAD_GPIO_17__GPIO7_IO12      0x80000000
                /* Wifi Slow Clock */
                MX6QDL_PAD_ENET_RXD0__OSC32K_32K_OUT    0x000b0
                /* Audio Clock */
                MX6QDL_PAD_GPIO_0__CCM_CLKO1        0x130b0
                /* Audio reset */
                MX6QDL_PAD_GPIO_19__GPIO4_IO05      0x178b0
                /* Camera Clock */
                MX6QDL_PAD_GPIO_3__CCM_CLKO2        0x130b0
                /* Resistive touch irq */
                MX6QDL_PAD_DISP0_DAT4__GPIO4_IO25   0x178b0
            >;
        };
        ... /* Other definitions */
    };
};
```

I read the following [documentation](https://developer.toradex.com/device-tree-customization#overwriting-nodes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite a node as long as you have labled it. A label has the form of `label: node@0x1 { /* data */ };`

Lets take an example device tree named `main.dts`:

```
$ cat main.dts 
/dts-v1/;

/ {
        model = "Test device tree";
        #address-cells = <0>;
        #size-cells = <1>;

        iomuxc: iomuxc@0x1 {
                reg = <0x1>;
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_hog>;

                imx6qdl-var-som-mx6 {
                        pinctrl_hog: hoggrp {
                                fsl,pins = <
                                        0x1b8 0x588 0x000 0x5 0x0 0x80000000
                                        /* more pins */
                                >;
                        };
                };
        };
};

&pinctrl_hog {
        fsl,pins = <
                0x1b8 0x588 0x000 0x5 0x0 0x89999999
                /* more pins */
        >;
};
```

Here, I overwrite the pin control for the label `pinctrl_hog`.  You can validate the output by compile and decompile the device tree:

```
$ dtc -I dts -O dtb -o out.dtb main.dts # compile 
$ dtc -I dtb -O dts out.dtb 
/dts-v1/;

/ {
        model = "Test device tree";
        #address-cells = <0x0>;
        #size-cells = <0x1>;

        iomuxc@0x1 {
                reg = <0x1>;
                pinctrl-names = "default";
                pinctrl-0 = <0x1>;

                imx6qdl-var-som-mx6 {

                        hoggrp {
                                fsl,pins = <0x1b8 0x588 0x0 0x5 0x0 0x89999999>;
                                linux,phandle = <0x1>;
                                phandle = <0x1>;
                        };
                };
        };
};
```

As you can see, the pins is set to `0x89999999` instead of the original `0x80000000`. Just make sure that the label exists before you use it. Normally, just as in C, you include the header on top of your file.

I hope this helps ;-)